# Remove additional quotes from python list

Tags: python

I have a list with below pattern and i want to get rid of `"` which is present at the beginning and end of each sub list. I tried replace, strip but they are not the attribute of list and therefore gives `AttributeError`.

```
lst = [["'123', 'Name1', 'Status1'"], ["'234', 'Name2', 'Status2'"]]
```

I am looking for below as my final result:

```
lst = [['123', 'Name1', 'Status1'], ['234', 'Name2', 'Status2']]
```

Please suggest how to remove double quotes from each sub list.

Comment: Can you share the output you're trying to get? It would make the question clearer.

Comment: You are aware that currently each list contain just 1 string item?

Comment: Could you explain what output you're looking for? Currently, `lst` contains two lists, each of which contains a single string. (And neither of those strings include double quotes.)

Comment: I understand that each list contains only one item which is not correct and i want to make it as three. I have update the output required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) after *removing* commas with `replace`:

```
import shlex

lst = [["'123', 'Name1', 'Status1'"], ["'234', 'Name2', 'Status2'"]]
r = [shlex.split(x[0].replace(',', '')) for x in lst]
# [['123', 'Name1', 'Status1'], ['234', 'Name2', 'Status2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
result = [[element.strip("'") for element in sub_list[0].split(', ')] for sub_list in lst]
```

I'm assuming that the format for the string is "strings wrapped in single quotes separated by commas and spaces." Note that my code will probably not do the expected thing with input like `[["'A comma here, changes the parsing', 'no comma here'"], ...]`. (This would look to my code like three elements in a list, while I imagine you want to consider it two.)

**EDIT**

This is perhaps easier to understand as compared to the longer list comprehension:

```
result = []
for sub_list in lst:
    s = sub_list[0]
    result.append([element.strip("'") for element in s.split(', ')])
```